# Вопрос по ООП в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Стоит задача сформировать нужный шаблон для разного типа данных. Скажем, есть массив:

```
$posts = array(
0 => array('type' => 'news', 'title' => 'News war'),
1 => array('type' => 'video', 'title' => 'Play funny video'),
2 => array('type' => 'article', 'title' => 'About...'),
...
);
```

Для каждого вида данных (**type**) - это может быть видео, новость, статьи и т.д. - я хочу определить выходной, готовый шаблон HTML, который будет содержать эти данные для отображения.

Сейчас я создал классы с наследованием:

```
class Template {

public $id;
public $title;
public $text;
public $description;
public $data = array();
public $content_html;
public $width_content = 500;
public $type;
public $time;
public $user;
public $category;
protected $CI;

// The next code works for a one element of array $data
function __construct($data = array()){
    $this->title    = $data['title'];
    $this->text     = $data['text'];
    $this->category = $data['category'];
    $this->type     = $data['type'];
    $this->time     = $data['time'];

    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->user = new InformationUser($data);

    //TODO
   }
}

class Articles extends Template {
}

class News extends Template {
}

class Init {
   public $posts = array('type' => 2);
}
```

В моем случае класс Template - родительский, который содержит общие объекты для всех типов данных (title, id, text и т.д.).

Далее для каждого отдельного типа данных я создал класс: **Articles**, **News**.

Начальной точкой является класс **Init**. Внутри этого класса доступен тот самый массив: **$posts**. В каждом массиве, как вы заметили, есть значение **type**, которое определяет, какой объект класса я должен создать. 
Например:

```
class Init {
  function define(){
     foreach($this->posts as $val){
      if($val['type'] == 2){
        $article = new Articles($val);
        //TODO $articles
      } else if($val['type'] == 3){
        $news = new News($val);
         //TODO $news
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Я знаю, что это не вариант, так как лучше передать весь массив **$post** в конкретный класс. Но я не могу сделать это без прохождения массива в цикле и определения **type** и узнать, к какому классу отдать массив данных на обработку.

Мне нужно, чтобы для различного типа элемента массива работал отдельный класс (для новостей - класс Новости, статьи - класса Статьи и т.д.).

Возможно, я ошибаюсь в архитектуре классов.
Что вы мне посоветуете?

Comment: В чем собственно заключается вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что как можно иначе представить эту структуру классов, или же допилить эту, сейчас для каждого элемента массива создается отдельный экземпляр класса

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, если переживаете за количество объектов (что зря), то идите от противоположного - сделайте три ***рендерера***, которые загружают в себя шаблон, а потом применяют его к тому, что в них попадает. В целом тут нет чего-то критично неправильного, лента разномастных событий всегда будет представлена виджетами с разными шаблонами, здесь проблемы только с грязной архитектурой - у Template явно не должно быть столько таких свойств.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно сгодится фабрика , этот процесс называется полиморфизм . Определите общий интерфейс , типичные публичные методы с которыми будет работать клиентский код . в итоге ваша фабрика будет возвращать экземпляр того класса который вам нужен , то есть ваша фабрика будет выглядеть так :

```
class Init
{
    public static function define()
    {
        foreach ($this->posts as $val) {
            if ($val['type'] == 2) {
                $obj = new Articles($val);
                //TODO $articles
            } else if ($val['type'] == 3) {
                $obj = new News($val);
                //TODO $news
            }
        }
        return $obj ; 
    }
}
```

Соответственно на клиенте вы делаете так :

```
$instance = Init::define($val)
```

Вообще есть оч хорошая книжка по поводу антивелосипедов [PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5648968/)

Comment: redroid, вам бы аккуратности в коде. $this в static если и будет, то только из-за косяка PHP, названия очень неинтуитивные.

Comment: Верное замечание , но это копипаст . Когда я показал код клиента я подразумевал что в статику будет передаваться параметр . В php такого косяка нет , статика ничего не знает об окружение .

Comment: Хм, починили. Раньше вызванный внутри обычно метода статичный метод получал в нагрузку $this из родительской области видимости, было очень забавно.

Answer (score 1):

Абстрактная фабрика не годится?

Comment: Не знаю ее сути - просмотрю, может сгодится.